# Error al hacer map en Observable con Angular

Tags: angular

Con el servicio `bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName()` cargo en mi `observable` **bookList$** todos los libros que tengo en mi db. Cada libro tiene una propiedad **url_image** y necesito limpiarla, para esto utilice un `map` (no se si es lo correcto) en el **bookList$** en donde intento pasarle a la funcion **linkImg()** esta **url_image**. Pero `Angular` en la funcion **getBooksWithAuthorName()** me informa el siguiente error:

**Type 'Observable<string[]>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Book[]>'.
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Book[]'.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Book'.ts(2322)**

aca `component.ts`

```js
bookList$: Observable<Book[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.getBooksWithAuthorName();
}

getBooksWithAuthorName() {
    this.bookList$ = this.bookService.getBooksWithAuthorName()
    .pipe(
      map((books: Book[]) => books.map(book => this.linkImg(book.url_image))     
    ));
  }

  linkImg(urlImage) {
    // quito la palabra public
    let str = urlImage.replace(/public/g, '');
    // quito la barra '\'
    str = str.replace('\\', '');
    // invierto la barra en sentido a '/'
    str = str.replace('\\', '/');
    // console.log(str);
    const URL = 'http://localhost:4000/';
    const link = URL + str;
    // console.log(link);
    return link;
  }
```

aca el servicio `book.service.ts`

```js
getBooksWithAuthorName() {
   return this.http.get<Book[]>(this.URL_API + 'AuthorName');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se debe a que lo siguiente esta retornando un string que es el `book.url.image`:

```
 map((books: Book[]) => books.map(book => this.linkImg(book.url_image))
```

Necesitas retornar el objeto, lo correcto sería:

```
 map((books: Book[]) => books.map(book => { 
   return {
     ...book , 
     url_image: this.linkImg(book.url_image)
   } 
 })
```